# Sentinel-2 product 2A SCL visualization parameter

Tags: python, sentinel-2, geemap

I am attempting to mask a Sentinel-2 scene using the SCL layer in a Python API using GEE compatibility. I have managed to visualize the SCL. However I do no think that I am viewing it properly. Does anyone know what vis parameters are necessary for this band of sentinal-2 2A SLC

```
def s2_clear_sky(image):
  # 1.Locate SCL product
  scl = S2_filt_de_2020.select('SCL')

  # 2.Apply mask to the image
  # Select values: 1) greater than 3 and less than 7 or 2) equal to 11
  wantedPixels = scl.eq(0).And(scl.lt(9)) \
                              .And(scl.gt(10))
  return image.updateMask(wantedPixels)

SCLvis = {'min': 1, 'max': 11, 'bands': ['SCL']}

Map.addLayer(S2_filt_de_2020, SCLvis, 'cloud mask')
```